# Entering external identifier

Tags: webservices

I've been viewing Wolfram webinars that use Wikidata.  The presenter enters "external identifiers" as arguments.  How does one enter one of these external identifiers?  For example:

[image]

Comment: [`WikidataSearch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WikidataSearch.html)

Comment: @JasonB. I think they mean programmatically, if they already have the id

Comment: @M.R. - like in the first example on the [`ExternalIdentifier`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalIdentifier.html) ref page?

Comment: What I don't understand, using Jason's link to WikidataSearch, is how you get the arguments into In[3].

Comment: I think he wants ExternalIdentifier[“Wikidata”, “autocomplete here...”] but not sure

Comment: It's just that from the examples it appears that the External Identifier is somehow placed into the Wikidatadata function.  I can do this by first using WikidataSearch and then copying and pasting.  I don't know if that's the way it's supposed to be done.